# flutter null safety The argument type 'String?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String'

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-null-safety

I am using null safety in my flutter app and i am trying to map a map to a walkthrough screen widget. I have looked and not seen solutions online. Here is my map

```
final pageViewModel = [
{
  'title': 'Budget Your Funds And Save Up',
  'subtitle': 'Save Up Your Money Over A Period Of Time and Get',
  'image': 'assets/images/budget.svg'
},
{
  'title': 'Transfer Funds At Almost No Cost',
  'subtite': 'Our Transfer Rates Are At Absolutely No Cost.',
  'image': 'assets/images/finance.svg'
},
{
  'title': 'Get Free Virtual Cards',
  'subtitle': 'Your Days Of Going To The Bank Is Over'
}
];
```

Then in my build method I am using this map list to create a pageviewmodel like so

```
IntroductionScreen(
  pages: pageViewModel
      .map((page) => PageViewModel(
            titleWidget: Text(
              page['title'], //Here is the line causing the error
              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              style: TextStyle(
                  color: secondaryColor,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w800,
                  fontSize: 25.0),
            ),
            body:
                "Here you can write the description of the page, to explain someting...",
            image: SvgPicture.asset(
              'assets/images/budget.svg',
              height: 400,
            ),
          ))
      .toList(),
```

The error i get is

```
The argument type 'String?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String'
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: you're not handling the null safety... you let that parameter be optional and you didn't unwrapped using "!" at the end of it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to Resolve The Argument type 'String?' can't be assign to parameter type 'String'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67495492/how-to-resolve-the-argument-type-string-cant-be-assign-to-parameter-type-st)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you create your `pageViewModel` array, you are not using any types there, just putting some objects in the array. As a result, the compiler cannot say that `page['title']` is not null - its type is dynamic. To avoid that, you can create a model class:

```
class YourViewModel {
  final String title;
  final String subtitle;
  final String? image;

  const YourViewModel({
    required this.title,
    required this.title, 
    this.image,
  });
}
```

Then, your `pageViewModel` would look like this:

```
final pageViewModel = <YourViewModel>[
  YourViewModel(
    title: 'Budget Your Funds And Save Up',
    subtitle: 'Save Up Your Money Over A Period Of Time and Get',
    image: 'assets/images/budget.svg'
  ),
  YourViewModel(
    title: 'Transfer Funds At Almost No Cost',
    subtite: 'Our Transfer Rates Are At Absolutely No Cost.',
    image: 'assets/images/finance.svg'
  ),
  YourViewModel(
    title: 'Get Free Virtual Cards',
    subtitle: 'Your Days Of Going To The Bank Is Over'
  ),
];
```

All done, you should not get the error in the UI!

**Bonus solution (not recommended and hacky one unless you know what you are doing):**

**If you are 100% sure** that title is never null, you can use the bang operator:

`page['title']!`

That should work, but in case the title is null at any point, you will get a wild run-time null pointer exception.