# (Flutter) Error: The argument type 'String?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String' because 'String?' is nullable and 'String' isn't

Tags: firebase, flutter, android-studio

im using flutter in android studio. coding as below.

```
class _loginscreenState extends State<loginscreen> {
  GlobalKey<FormState> formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  String? _email, _password;

  void signin() async {
    await FirebaseAuth.instance
        .signInWithEmailAndPassword(email: _email, password: _password)
        .catchError((onError) {
      print(onError);
    }).then((authUser) => {print(authUser.user?.uid)});
  }
```

please help me to solve this why the code cant run and what is the meaning of "'String?' is nullable and 'String' isn't". and what is the solution?

Answer (score 1):

```dart
void signin() async { 
   await FirebaseAuth.instance .signInWithEmailAndPassword(
      email: _email! /* <-- */, 
      password: _password! /* <-- */).catchError((onError) {
        print(onError);
      }).then((authUser) => print(authUser.user?.uid));
}
```

try to add null(!)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
class _loginscreenState extends State<loginscreen> {
  GlobalKey<FormState> formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  String? _email, _password;

  void signin() async {
    await FirebaseAuth.instance
    //here change email -->email.tostring() and passsword--->password.tostring()
        .signInWithEmailAndPassword(email: _email.toString(), password: _password.toString())
        .catchError((onError) {
      print(onError);
    }).then((authUser) => {print(authUser.user?.uid)});
  }
```

Here you must supply email and password.if it was String?. may or maynot it contain null value .so Avoiding that `email.tostring()` we can use `tostring()` .if email is a null value it will converted to "Null" after adding `email.toString()` .

Answer (score 0):

this is caused by using sound null safety in your app
and you are passing a nullable string to a non-nullable string
some solutions are:

1. you can assert that the values for _email, _password are non-null strings
2. or using the bang operator

for more elaboration on this[string is null and string isnt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66798782/error-the-argument-type-string-cant-be-assigned-to-the-parameter-type-stri)
or [how to resolve argument type string...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67495492/how-to-resolve-the-argument-type-string-cant-be-assign-to-parameter-type-st)

Answer (score 0):

You have made `String? _email, _password;` email and password nullable.
after that you haven't initialized the value of email and password. and you are directly using email and password inside `FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithEmailAndPassword` which does not support null values.
Try initializing the value of email and password.

You can use TextEditingController if you are fetching value from textfield. and pass the value of email and password as parameter.

```
 TextEditingController emailController = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController passwordController = TextEditingController();
```

```
Future<String> signUp(
      {required String email, required String password}) async {
  final FirebaseAuth _auth;


      await _auth
          .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password: password);
```

Then use this function.

```
signUp(email: nameController.text,password: passwordController.text);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class _loginscreenState extends State<loginscreen> {
  GlobalKey<FormState> formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  String _email, _password;

  void signin() async {
    await FirebaseAuth.instance
        .signInWithEmailAndPassword(email: _email, password: _password)
        .catchError((onError).toString() {
      print(onError);
    }).then((authUser) => {print(authUser.user?.uid)});
  }
```